# OpenGL, C++ -> How do you lay out objects on screen?

Tags: c++, opengl, layout, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

When I used to write java code, there were layout managers like "grid bag" and box.

I am working on a game using Cocos2D-X and running into trouble laying out objects on screen so that they are not hard coded positions but rather based upon a layout. The pixel difference between devices is what is causing my problems.

I know Cocos2D has ways to deal with this but my artwork is large and high quality and I want to size it based upon the device.

So I am thinking just going native OpenGL but try as I might I cannot figure out if there are layout managers already available.

Can anyone discuss the ways one might layout objects in OpenGL? C++

Comment: OpenGL itself has no functionality for this. And never will. This is strictly in the realm of add-on libraries.

Comment: darn, I was afraid that I was going to have to write my own. Could be worse! :-)

Comment: What kind of objects are you talking about? Images?

Comment: yup, images, sprites, etc. Essentially so I can layout where they should go and if users resolutions differ (retina and non-retina as example) then the images is in the same place on the screen. You cannot hardcode an x-y because that location is different between devices.

Comment: Make sure you get your (x,y) coordinate system right to begin with so that a square actually draw as a square. I made quick and dirty window and container system for my engine a long time ago only for drawing debug information and making some simple tools. It works on a [-1,1] x and y range no matter what the aspect ratio is for the screen resolution. It's a nightmare to work with! :D

Comment: @Grimmy, any chance of sharing to help me get a head start on my coding today?

Comment: I'm thinking that since I always have the screen size that I load the images and sprites to look right on a 1024 x 768 (we are always landscape), create a layout based upon that size and then multiply by 4 for retina display as I think that Apple says 4 retina pixels - 1 "normal" pixel.

Comment: In OpenGL (like any other half-decent drawing/rendering library) you can work in your own coordinate system for the screen (or viewports.) The system most people use is either (-1..1) or (0..1). That means that your coordinates are not integers in [0..1024) or some similar number, but floating-point values in the (-1..1) range. In this system, if you place an image (i.e. texture) at (-0.5,-0.5) to (0.5,0.5), it will cover a quarter of the screen, no matter the final pixel dimensions of the device you end up rendering on.

Comment: By the way, in this method of managing coordinates, you need to be aware of and handle screen *aspect ratio*. Because a shape that looks like an square on one screen, may become an oblong rectangle on another (although it still has the same *relative* placement and area.) The way to handle this (usually) is to fix the range of coordinates in one dimension, e.g. X-axis, to (0..1) and calculate the other, Y-axis, based on the aspect ratio. For example, for a 4-to-3 screen, the range along the X axis is (0..1) and the rang along the Y axis becomes (0 .. 0.75).

Comment: Just because no one else mentioned it, you are never gonna get pixel perfect results from scaling down high resolution resources.

Comment: if they are vector based graphics then one is better off...

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL has the concept of a Viewport. This is the box in screen/window co-ordinates that you are going to be drawing into. Once you set the viewport, you are now using what is sometimes termed Camera coordinates.

Camera coordinates go from -1.0 on the extreme left of the viewport to 1.0 on the extremeright. Similarly for Y coordinates -1.0 on the extreme bottom and 1.0 on the extreme top. Anything that lies outside the viewport is not draw.

Your models can exist in any coordinate system you like. You then transform your objects into camera coordinates using transformation matrices.

Comment: I'm sorry, I dont understand this at all :-( I read it 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

No need to go Opengl for this, instead of working in pixels for positioning your artwork; you could actually position them based on an screen percentage.

If its background image you could position it by 
     CCSize size = CCDirector::....->getWinSize();
     x = size.width/2;
     y = size.height/2;
     image->setPosition(x,y);
if the anchor point of the image is the center, the image will be centered.

If you have a lot of artwork, it would be different.

ADDED MORE(Updated)

```
retina = 2048×1536  
normal = 1024×768
retinaWidth = normal.width * 2;//(2048)
retinaHeight = normal.height * 2;//(1536)


spriteInNormalRes{
    x = 250px(which you will define with the percentage, in my first answer)
    y = 264px(which you will define with the percentage, in my first answer)
}
spriteInRetinaRes{
    x = spriteInNormalRes.x * 2 
    y = spriteInNormalRes.x * 2 
}
```

you can double the x,y to position the sprites.
 + custom scaleRatio to resize them at your desired size.

Note: you cannot necessarily double the values, test for the right ones for you.

Comment: The backgrounds are fine. I get that. What I am struggling with is the other sprites, like characters, etc. I can make them look good on an iPad Mini but moving to a retina display the sprites can be bigger and the position on the screen is different because of the higher resolution....

Comment: added more into the answer. :D

Comment: You do have a typo, right in `spriteInRetinaRes` `y = spriteInNormalRes.x * 2 ` should be y*2?

Comment: Yes there is i typo. And yes i mean (0.5, 0.5) which is the default, so no need to set it.